# Optimisation suggestions for Min Heap

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, heap

Can someone please optimisations for my implementation of min heap.Its performance is poor compared to the heapq module in python. My use case for the MinHeap class is 'N' insertions and extractions where N > 1,000,000.

```
import math


class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.__items = arr
        self.build_heap()

    def size(self):
        """
        Returns the size of heap.
        """
        return len(self.__items)

    def items(self):
        """
        Returns the elements in the heap.
        """
        return self.__items

    def build_heap(self):
        """
        Builds heap using the list of elements.
        """
        for node_number in xrange(int(len(self.__items) / 2), 0, -1):
            self.heapify(node_number)

    def heapify(self, node_number):
        """
        Ensure that node follows heap property.
        """
        # return if leave node
        if node_number > int(len(self.__items) / 2):
            return

        node = self.__items[node_number-1]
        left_child = self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1] if (((2 * node_number)-1) < len(self.__items)) else None 

        right_child = self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1] if (((2 * node_number + 1)-1) < len(self.__items)) else None        

        min_node = node

        if left_child != None and right_child != None:
            min_node = min(node, left_child, right_child)
        elif left_child != None :
            min_node = min(node, left_child)
        elif right_child != None :
            min_node = min(node, right_child)

        if min_node == node:
            return
        elif left_child!=None and min_node == left_child:

            self.__items[node_number - 1], self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1] = self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1], self.__items[node_number - 1]
            self.heapify(2 * node_number)
        elif right_child!=None and min_node == right_child:

            self.__items[node_number - 1], self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1] = self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1], self.__items[node_number - 1]
            self.heapify(2 * node_number + 1)

    def extract_min(self):
        """
        Returns the minimum element.
        """
        length = len(self.__items)
        if length == 0:
            return
        self.__items[0], self.__items[length-1] = self.__items[length-1], self.__items[0]
        min_element =  self.__items.pop()
        self.heapify(1);
        return min_element

    def insert(self, num):
        """
        Inserts a new element in the heap.
        """
        self.__items.append(num)
        current_node = len(self.__items)
        parent_node = int(current_node / 2)
        while current_node > 1:
            min_node = min(self.__items[current_node-1], self.__items[parent_node-1])
            if min_node == self.__items[parent_node-1]:
                break
            self.__items[current_node-1], self.__items[parent_node-1] = self.__items[parent_node-1], self.__items[current_node-1]
            current_node = parent_node
            parent_node = int(current_node / 2)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `heapq` (or a wrapper around it) if it is faster?

Comment: @Graipher I think [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's what I thought at first as well, but then they mentioned their use case explicitly, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Graipher I'm just trying to write the MinHeap class from scratch and optimise it to the point where its as efficient as 'heapq'

Comment: (I'd rather `please` girls (grey-haired to fully grown) than `optimisations`, competence not withstanding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docstrings with every method: Way to go, document `MinHeap`, too and revisit [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) for details.
Your `MinHeap` tackles the same task as module `heapq` using much the same strategy, and you express dissatisfaction with run time - a *side by side* comparison:

- in *many* places, you compute something like `node_number` or `parent_node` to *repeatedly* index `__items` - not using that variable, but something like `parent_node - 1`
  (Code the way you think about it: if there are multiple places where you want the element at index `i-1`, write `a[i-1]`, `b[i-1]`…, if you think *same index happening to be `i-1`*, write `j = i-1`, `a[j]`, `b[j]`…)
  (An *optimising compiler* can be expected to *eliminate common sub-expressions*; that is more difficult for an interpreter to justify (and I seem to remember why it might be *hard* for python).)
- `insert()` assigns the new value to every candidate position, while `heapq._siftdown()/heappush()` just *moves down* items of lesser priority and puts the new item once/twice.
- `extract_min()` swaps the items at both ends instead of just replacing the top priority item (see `heapq.heappop()`)
- `heapify()` conditionally assigns `None` to `left_child` and `right_child` to go on and conditionally execute statements comparing these values to `None` (using `!=` instead of `is`&`not`)

  - `heapq._siftup()` uses the *realistic* approach of *not* comparing values "on the way down": half the nodes are leaf nodes, it is much more likely that the new item will end up near the bottom of the heap.
- heapq introduces `heappushpop()` as a "Fast version of a heappush followed by a heappop."

You seem to be bent on thinking of nodes numbered starting from 1 - nothing wrong with that, and coding the way you think about a solution/problem is the only sane way to start:
for a shot from the hip, allocate one more array element, don't use index 0 and *drop all of "the `- 1`"*.